# Zero characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible that characteristic polynomial of an $n \times n$ matrix be the zero polynomial? If this happens, this means that any scalar would serve as an eigenvalue?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial must be of degree $n$, so no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Per John: The characteristic polynomial must be of degree $n$, so no, it's not possible.