# Can a non-zero matrix have a zero characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, characteristic-polynomial

Are there some field $\mathbb{F}$, some $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$, and some non-zero $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{F}$, whose characteristic polynomial $p_A(t)$ is identically $0$?

The same question was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1287518/37058) here in the past, and the answer explained that such a $p_A(t)$ was impossible, because a characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix had degree $n$.

But this answer is unsatisfactory, because in some cases an identically zero polynomial has a positive degree: take for instance the polynomial $p(t) = t^5 + 4t$ in the field $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ of the integers modulo $5$.

Comment: No. The characteristic polynomial has leading term $t^n$ or $\left(-1\right)^nt^n$, depending on how you define it.

Comment: Usually people would interpret "zero characteristic polynomial" as meaning all the coefficients are zero rather than the polynomial being zero as a function. The two notions agree in characteristic 0, but not over finite fields, say. Anyway, any polynomial of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n (t-\lambda_i)$ where $\lambda_i$ are in your field is a characteristic polynomial (use a diagonal matrix). [So, using the algebraic closure, you can immediately get examples of your sort] <--- whoops, spoke too quickly.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: It looks like you haven't read my post.

Comment: However, if you mean that the polynomial becomes $0$ when evaluated on any element of the base field, then yes, this is possible: Every monic polynomial (or $\left(-1\right)^n$-monic polynomial, depending on the definition) can be obtained as the characteristic polynomial of a matrix (e.g., of its [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)).

Comment: Note that a polynomial is not the same as a polynomial function, for the very reason that different polynomials may give rise to the same function. The characteristic *polynomial* of a matrix is never zero. You are asking whether it may still correspond to a zero function.  Note that this can only happen over a finite field, since for infinite fields the map from polynomials to functions is injective.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I believe you can post this as an answer.

Comment: @Evan Aad What you are asking is possible, but you have a wrong definition of a polynomial. Polynomials are not functions, they are formal expressions. This is very important to remember, because the whole theory is built on this definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about characteristic *polynomials*, then the answer to the question that you have mentioned is correct: it has degree $n$, and therefore it cannot be the null *polynomial*.

But if you are talking about *polynomial functions*, then, yes, the polynomial function corresponding to the characteristic polynomial of a matrix can by the null *function*. Take, for instance $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Then $p_A(t)=t^2-t$. So, if you are working over the field $\Bbb F_2$, you will get the null function (but *not* the null *polynomial*).

Comment: Thank you. Incidentally, when people talk about *roots* of a polynomial, for instance, when they say that the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, is this concept of "roots" defined with respect to the view of a polynomial as a formal algebraic structure or to view of a polynomial as a function?

Comment: It's the same thing. If $p(x)\in F[x]$, for some field $F$, and $a\in F$, then saying that $a$ is root of $p(x)$ either means (depending upon the definition that you are using) that $(x-a)\mid p(x)$ (in which case you are treating $p(x)$ as a polynomial) or that $p(a)=0$ (in which case you are treating $p(x)$ as a function). But these two assertions are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Polynomials are not functions. $t^5+4t$ is *not* the zero polynomial over $\Bbb Z_5$. It evaluates to zero everywhere, so it becomes the zero function. But it is **not** the zero polynomial, as it has non-zero coefficients.

Thus, the argument you have already come across proves that the characteristic polynomial of a matrix can never be the zero polynomial.